# Stop threads from eating up all resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have written a program in QT using several threads for doing important stuff in the background. The target for this program is a BeagleBone Black (Single-Core-CPU). But in my tests on my computer (VM, 4 Cores of i7) the separate threads are already eating up two of the four cores as seen in htop (maybe because in two of them a `while(condition){}-loop` is running). How can I prevent these threads from eating up all my resources, so that I will be able to run this multi-thread-program without speed loss on a single-core-arm-cpu? How can I find out which threads are eating up all my cpu resources?

Comment: if your while loops have no blocking calls (sleep, i/o read, wait, etc...) then search no further...

Comment: What are your threads doing? Are they sometimes waiting in these loops or are they actively doing stuff?

Comment: They are waiting for signals, and if signals are incoming, then they do some stuff. I only use the while-loops for keeping them alive. Is there a better possibility?

Comment: @arc_lupus: How do you wait for signals? Are you spinning, i.e. `while(is_not_signalled){}`? If so, that's your problem. Either add a small sleep in the loop, or use some blocking mechanism for the signals to arrive, like condition variables or a blocking read. *It would really help to know what kind of signal you're waiting for, i.e. where does it come from, how do you obtain its state and so on.*

Comment: No, my while-loops look like: `while(!stop_condition){}`. Can I be sure that my signals will arrive if I add a small sleep in the loop?

Comment: Showing an example of your code in the question would be much better than trying to describe the problem.

Comment: @Merlin069: Which part of my code would be best suited? My code has around 2000 lines, thus I don't want to post everything...

Comment: Do not post all your code, but create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Merlin069: That is going to need some time, thus I will not able to do it within the next few hours.

Comment: The problem you may have here, without code, is that the answers provided are just educated guesses as to the problem you may be having. While they may be good answers, they may not be solving your actual problem in the most efficient way. Perhaps there's an obvious, simple reason to your issue, but without seeing example code, we'll never know for sure. For example, I'd question the need for multithreading the app on a single core - do you really need it here? Perhaps, but I can't know for sure. What are the different threads doing? Can you time slice the work required and is that better?

Comment: @Merlin069: The different threads are responsible for controlling external devices and waiting for their answer without freezing the main gui thread. My whole code is on github, too (Link if requested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using Qt, there's a better possibility for making your threads wait. You could indeed use [**`QWaitCondition`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html)s.

This allows you to make your thread block until a certain condition is met in another thread for example. This thread then can notify either all threads  that are waiting that the condition has been met, and then wake them, or just one depending on your need (though through one `QWaitCondition` you can't determine/predict which one will be notified, that depends on the OS).

In case you need a more general resource about this topic (idleness), I invite you to read the article [**In praise of idleness**](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/in-praise-of-idleness/) which covers this topic more thoroughly.

Comment: If I understood that right, I have to replace my signals with wait conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "signals"? Do you imply variables that you check within the loop condition to see if the thread should work, or Qt's signals? Ideally, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of what you're doing.

Comment: I am signalising the thread to stop via sending a signal which is received by a function running in this thread.

Comment: Ok, and what does this function do?

Comment: Example: `void DPC::cancelThread(void)
{
    DPC::runThread = false;
}`, Main Loop: `while(DPC::runThread){}`

Comment: Yep, so you're checking actively that a variable takes a specific value. You could replace those "signals" by wait conditions as explained here. Just simply create a `QWaitCondition`, then in the thread that must wait, create a mutex, **lock it using a locker**, then call `wait()` with this mutex. Then in the thread that signal other threads, calls `wakeAll()` or `wakeOne()` when the other threads should run.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using waitConditions you can also use the event loop to sequence the code

What will need to happen is that each function in the form of:

```
void Worker::foo(){
    //some code
    while(!stop_condition){}
    //other code
}

void Worker::signalCondition(){
    stop_condition=true;
}
```

has to be translated to:

```
void Worker::foo(){
    //some code

}

//actual slot called with queuedConnection
void Worker::signalCondition(){
    //other code
}
```

This means Worker needs to be moved to the other thread or the signalCondition will be called on the wrong thread.

admittedly the code change for using QWaitConditions is simpler:

```
void Worker::foo(){
    //some code
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        while(!stop_condition){
            waitCondition.wait(&mutex);
        }
    }
    //other code
}

void Worker::signalCondition(){
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    stop_condition=true;
    waitCondition.wakeOne();
}
```